# Я не могу зайти в UEFI на ноутбуке packard bell

Tags: linux, bios, uefi

Я перепробовал все кнопки от f1 до f12, пробовал ctrl-alt-delete, ctrl-f2 (и да, я нажимал fn, так что проблема не в этом). Просто я примерно пол года назад ставил xubuntu вместо windows 8, и тогда UEFI работал. Теперь же максимум, что выходит - зайти в gnu grub. Самое странное - загрузочная флешка у меня та же, что и та, с которой я ставил xubuntu, стало быть, загрузка с неё должна быть с большим приоритетом, однако, видимо, компьютер её не видит при запуске

Comment: Для того, чтобы загрузиться с флешки, попробуйте перезагрузить компьютер, удерживая клавишу Shift - это один из трюков, указанных в вопросе на форуме Ubuntu: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189855

Comment: а просто во время того как перезагружается комп тыкать на `DELETE` пробовали ?

Comment: @dmtr уже пробовал

Comment: @DmitriChubarov с этим способом я опять же попадаю в grub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял, оказывается, что надо было зайдя в grub выполнить команду exit, тогда получиться загрузиться с флешки